# Sum of tensor product of orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

This is a homework question so I'd just like a nudge in the right direction.

Let $V$ be a vector space with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot) : V\times V\rightarrow k$ over a field $k$, and let $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a basis for $V$. Define the orthogonal basis $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ by $(v_i,u_j) =\delta_{ij}$.

Show that in the tensor product $V\otimes V$, the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\otimes u_i,$$ is independent of the choice of basis for $V$.

This is what I have so far:

Let $\{v_i'\}$ be another basis for $V$. And let $\{u_i'\}$ be its corresponding orthogonal basis. Then for all $i$, $v_i' = \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ji}v_j$, and $u_i' = \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_{ji}u_j$. Then we have $\delta_{ij} = (v_i',u_j') = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{ki}\beta_{kj}$.

Now we have, $\sum_i (v_i'\otimes u_i') = \sum_i\left(\sum_k\sum_\ell \alpha_{ki}\beta_{\ell i}(v_k\otimes u_\ell)\right)$.

But now I'm stuck and I don't know how to retrieve the original sum from what I have there.

Comment: You probably want to add that $\{u_i^{\prime}\}$ is a orthogonal basis with $\langle v_i^{\prime},u^{\prime}_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** You can write the equation $\delta_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{ki}\beta_{kj}$ as a matrix product; and this product happens to be commutative.

Comment: I don't see how bringing a matrix into the situation would help

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey It's the simplest way I can think of to obtain the commutativity I mentioned. This commutativity is what allows you to find $\sum_i \alpha_{ki}\beta_{\ell i}$ from $\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{ki}\beta_{kj}$.

Comment: Oh okay I see how it would help now. I just need to convince myself that the product is commutative.